# How to save a dictionary containing a list to a file?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary that has a key and a list as value. I'm trying to save this dictionary to a file and make it look a certain way. The dictionary looks like this:

`dic_ = { "name" : [number], "name2" : [number2]}`

Now I want to save this to a file looking like this:
`number;name;`

I have tried this:

```
    with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
        for key, value in dic_.items():
            f.write('%s;%s;\n' % (value, key))
```

But then it saves like this `['number'];name;`, so I want to remove `[` , `'`  while saving.
I know that `strip()`can remove these things on strings but I dont know how to use it here or if it's even possible. Maybe there is some other way to remove it?

Help please.

Edit: Solved by using value[0] Thanks for the help

Comment: Don't do this. Serialise it as JSON using the json module.

Comment: You don't want to save the *list*, you want to save the *first item in the list*, which you can get by using `[0]`.

Comment: Specifically `value[0]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work out?:

```
with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
    for key, value in dic_.items():
        f.write('%s;%s;\n' % (value[0], key)) # added index 0 here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
        for key, value in dic_.items():
            f.write('%s;%s;\n' % (value[:], key))
```

Fixed